# How do I add a transparent US state map over my ggplot?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, border

I am using ggplot to create a map of US counties and their drug poisoning rates in 2004. I want to add a transparent map over top of this one that shows black borders of US states (not counties... with the counties filled in, I am looking for a way to create distinct borders between the states). Here is my code so far. The problem begins on the last few lines, marked by ##:

```
library(readr)
drugs <- read_csv("drugs.csv")
View(drugs)
summary(drugs)

library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(mapproj)
data(county.fips)

colnames(drugs)[7] <- "deaths"
sort(table(drugs$deaths))
drugs$death_rate <- 0
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "<2", 1, 
                                       drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "2-3.9", 2, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "4-5.9", 3, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "6-7.9", 4, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "8-9.9", 5, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "10-11.9", 6, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "12-13.9", 7, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "14-15.9", 8, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "16-17.9", 9, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "18-19.9", 10, 
                                    drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "20-21.9", 11, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "22-23.9", 12, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "24-25.9", 13, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "26-27.9", 14, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "28-29.9", 15, 
                           drugs$death_rate)
drugs$death_rate <- ifelse(drugs$deaths == "30+", 16, 
                           drugs$death_rate)


drugdeaths <- merge(drugs, county.fips, by.x = "FIPS", by.y = "fips")
counties <- map_data("county")
head(counties)
ggcounties <- mutate(counties, polyname = paste(region, subregion, sep = ","))
head(ggcounties)
county_coords <- left_join(ggcounties, drugdeaths, by = "polyname")
head(county_coords)
ggmap <- county_coords[order(county_coords$death_rate), ]
ggplot(ggmap, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=death_rate)) + 
  geom_polygon() + coord_map() + theme_map()

##PROBLEM STARTS BELOW:
drugdeaths2004 <- subset(ggmap, ggmap$Year=="2004")
ggplot(drugdeaths2004, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=death_rate)) + 
  geom_polygon() + coord_map() + theme_map() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend()) + labs(fill = 
  "Death Rate 
Per 100k People") + 
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Purples", direction = 1)
```

Please let me know how I can add state borders over top of my ggplot. I have tried using the `map()` command -

```
map("state", col = "black", fill = FALSE, resolution = 0, lty = 0,  projection = "mercator", add = TRUE)
```

but I get an error that says

> "Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Hi OP - [have you seen this reference](https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html)?  It's very helpful to understand how to draw maps with `ggplot`.

Comment: `map()` is a base R command, so does not work with ggplot directly. Your error comes because `maps::map()` has been masked by `purrr::map` - part of tidyverse. `case_when` is probably nicer than your long ifelse section (and may be even better solutions)